# Import-CSV and Get-ADuser are returning nothing

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The command line is returning nothing when I'm using it.
I've already changed `Name` to `DisplayName` or `CN` but this wasn't working too.

```
Import-Csv "D:\Temp\userExcelRights.txt" |
  %{ Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "*$_*"} } |
  Select Name,Enabled,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
```

The CSV file contains the full name of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command it's working:

```
$data=@(Import-Csv "D:\Temp\userExcelRights.txt").Name 
$data | %{ Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '*$_*'" } |
  Select Name,Enabled,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
```

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers.

Answer (score 1):

The `-eq` operator doesn't support wildcard matches, you need to use the `-like` operator for that, and you must select a property from the objects that `Import-Csv` procuces. Also, avoid scriptblock syntax for `Get-ADUser` filters. Replace

```
{Name -eq "*$_*"}
```

with

```
"Name -like '*$($_.Name)*'"
```

If the subexpression doesn't work for you, you may need to expand the `Name` property before feeding it into the loop:

```
Import-Csv 'D:\Temp\userExcelRights.txt' |
  select -Expand Name |
  %{ Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '*$_*'" } |
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working the error was `Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -like '*@{Bellon`.I've tried this: `"Name -like '*$($_.Name)*'"`  and the error was `Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized`